# R: find two strings most commonly found together per category

Tags: r

I have a data frame (DF) with 3 columns: ID number, category, and brand:

```
ID             Category        Brand
00129          Bits            B89
00129          Bits            B87
00129          Bits            B87
00129          Logs            B32
00129          Logs            B27
00129          Logs            B27
00130          Bits            B12
00130          Bits            B14
00130          Bits            B14
00131          Logs            B32
00131          Logs            B27
00131          Logs            B32
00132          Bits            B77
00132          Bits            B89
00132          Bits            B89
```

I have 200 different categories and 2000 different brands.

I want to find the two brands per category bought together most often by id numbers:

```
Category       Brand
Bits           B89,B87
Logs           B32,B27
```

or:

```
#$Bits
    #[1] "B89" "B87"

#$Logs
    #[1] "B32" "B27"
```

The only way I could think of was to rework the data frame to look like this to make sure it is calculated with acknowledgment of different id numbers:

```
     B89   B87   B32   B27   B12   B14  
1    1     2     1     2     0     0
2    0     0     0     0     1     2
3    0     0     2     1     0     0
4    2     1     0     0     0     0
```

And then return the columns that are populated with values greater than 0 when a certain column is populated with values greater than 0.

```
list1 =(setNames(object = lapply(1:NCOL(df), function(i)
  unique(colnames(df)[-i][which(as.matrix(df[which(df[,i] > 0),i])>0,
                                   arr.ind = TRUE)[,2]])),
  nm = colnames(df)))
```

But then I sacrifice the category, which I need. Any thoughts on how to tackle this?

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick. Ended up with a combination of data.table and dplyr, because I am not really familiar with data.table yet.

```
dt = data.table(read.table(text="ID             category              brand
00129          Bits            B89
00129          Bits            B87
00129          Bits            B87
00129          Logs            B32
00129          Logs            B27
00129          Logs            B27
00130          Bits            B12
00130          Bits            B14
00130          Bits            B14
00131          Logs            B32
00131          Logs            B27
00131          Logs            B32
00132          Bits            B77
00132          Bits            B89
00132          Bits            B89",header=T))

library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

# get all combinations of two purchases.
dt = dt[,.(list(unique(brand))),.(ID,category)][, .(combn(unlist(V1), 2,simplify=FALSE)),.(ID,category)]

# concatenate those two purchases to a string
dt$V1 = unlist(lapply(dt$V1,function(x) {paste(x,collapse=", ")}))

# fetch only the top per category
dt %>% group_by(V1,category) %>% summarize(n=n()) %>% group_by(category) %>% top_n(n = 1) %>% select(-n)
```

Output:

```
        V1 category
1 B12, B14     Bits
2 B32, B27     Logs
3 B77, B89     Bits
4 B89, B87     Bits
```

Which I think is correct, considering your dataset, although it does not match your expected output?

Optionally add

```
dt %>% group_by(ID,category) %>% mutate(unique_types = n_distinct(brand)) %>% filter(unique_types>1)
```

in front if there are also purchases with just a single brand, since `combn(n,m)` will not work if `length(n)<m`